# Can compileSdkVersion be lower than targetSdkVersion?

Tags: android, flutter

Recently Play Store asked me to target my app to SDK 33.

My flutter app now compiles with sdk 31. To compile with 33 I will need to upgrate flutter version, and for that I will need to upgrade 10+ dependencies. For now I dont have time for that.

Changed the `targetSdkVersion 33` but left `compileSdkVersion 31` Android Studio shows error `The compileSdkVersion (31) should not be lower than the targetSdkVersion (33)`.

But I am able to build and publish the app like this.

What could be the down sides of doing this?

Comment: By setting your `targetSdkVersion` to 33, you're basically saying _"I have tested my app against Android 13 and I've handled all revelant [behavior changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13)"_. In some cases, handling such behavior changes may require using new APIs that won't be available to you at compile-time if you're using an older `compileSdkVersion`.